# apache http to https redirected you too many times

Tags: apache, http, https

I have a website. I want to use https only on the page so i looked up for a code for my .htaccess and I found the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On

     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

After adding the code to my .htaccess I reload the page an get an error: redirected you too many times.

After removing the code from the .htaccess I reloaded the page again. It works fine. If I reload the page with https manually it works fine too.

So why I get the error?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you figure out why this was happening?

Comment: Yes, it was a redirect from my software to the old URL. So my software wanted http and redirected from ssl and htaccess wanted to redirect again to https.

Answer (score 0):

I ran with the same problem and I resolved my issue using a much more simpler code for the `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```